# syntax errors in a Perl script

Tags: perl

At the risk of getting minus points by asking the question, I am seeking help for the errors Perl interpreter picks up. This is a homework question from Beginning Perl.

Q: Modify the currency program to keep asking for currency names until a valid currency name is entered.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
#convert.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($value, $from, $to, $rate, %rates);
%rates = (
    pounds => 1,
    dollars => 1.6,
    marks => 3,
    "french frances" => 10,
    yen => 174.8,
    "swiss frances" => 2.43,
    drachma => 492.3,
    euro => 1.5
);

print "currency exchange formula -
pounds, dollars, marks, french frances, 
yen, swiss frances, drachma, euro\n";


print "Enter your starting currency: ";
$from = <>;
chomp($from);

While ($from ne $rates{$from}) {

    print "I don't know anything about $from as a currency\n";
    print "Please re-enter your starting currency:";
    $from = <>;
    chomp($from);
    }

print "Enter your target currency: ";
$to =<>;
chomp($to) ;

While ($to ne $rates{$to}) {

    print "I don't know anything about $to as a currency\n";
    print "Please re-enter your target currency:";
    $to = <>;
    chomp($to);
    }


print "Enter your amount: ";
$value = <>;
chomp ($value);
    if ($value == 0) {
    print "Please enter a non-zero value";
    $value = <>;
    chomp ($value);
    }

$rate = $rates{$to} / $rates{$from};
print "$value $from is ", $value*$rate, " $to.\n";
```

4 errors were identified, all within the `while` loop, e.g. `"syntax error at line 27, near ") {"` or `...at line 33, near "}"` ... etc. The only thing I have in, for example line 27, is a whitespace between `")"` and `"{"`. The solution provided by the author, as far as I could see, is nearly identifical to my script except that the author uses `while (not exists $rates{$from}) { ... }`.
Did I misundertand the usage of "ne"? Or is anything else wrong with my script? Great many thanks.

Comment: yes, you misunderstood ne; I'm not sure what you thought it did do?

Comment: Questions don't always get down votes.  Bad questions (for example, ones that include the entire source file rather than the problematic bits) get down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `While` begins with a **capital W**.
Perl is case-sensitive, that should be a `while`.

Using `while (not exists $rates{$from}) { ... }` as you mentioned is correct. In your code, you are comparing the string `$from` with the number **corresponding to** `$from` in the `%rates` hash. This won't be true, in any case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Too bad I could only select one answer to give the "thumbs up".

Answer (score 3):

`ne` is "not equal to". Your first `while` loop uses it, but it will never get a false condition with the way you've written things. You'll always be stuck in that loop. A word will never match a number. That's why you want to check if the key does `not exists`.

The proper thing to do is to print out the currencies you do know, e.g. `say for keys %rates` and use a `do {...} while (...)` loop.

And, as Cthulhu mentioned, you're invoking `While` instead of the proper `while`.